# Plugin for CSS Transitions via jQuery addClass?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to easily use CSS Transitions via jQuery's `addClass` / `removeClass` / `toggleClass` functions.  i.e. I want these functions to do nothing (other than just adding a CSS class) in webkit, but use jQuery animations in IE.  jQueryUI replaces these 3 functions and comes close to what I need, but it only works on the exact element (e.g `$('#myID').addClass('foo');` doesn't animate `#myID.foo .someClass`)

I've looked around and can't find anything that does this, hopefully someone knows of one :)  If not, the solution requires:

1. parsing all stylesheets on the page for CSS transition properties
2. matching all stylesheets with transitions (e.g. `-webkit-transition`)
3. storing these stylesheets
4. on `addClass`, etc match current and down the tree (e.g. `.addedClass .someOtherClass`)
5. apply animations to all matched elements (or to the style rule)

So if anyone knows of any existing solutions to parse stylesheets (the text of them) or to animate a rule (instead of individual nodes), that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you want something like [jQuery++](http://jquerypp.com/#animate)

> jQuery.animate overwrites $.fn.animate to use CSS 3 animations if
>   possible. It takes the same arguments as the original $.fn.animate and
>   will fall back to jQuery’s JavaScript animation if a CSS animation is
>   not possible.

your proposed approach seems a little bit complicated to me, but maybe somebody comes up with a solution for this ;)